# Why did Missy want to do this?

Tags: doctor-who

Why, in *Doctor Who* S08E12 *Death in Heaven*, would Missy want to have

> put Clara together with the Doctor?

It was clearly suggested this was part of some master plan but I couldn't understand what that could have been.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the idea was that Clara had the necessary personality characteristics to make the Doctor do things, meaning that when

> Danny died

she could convince him to venture into the Nethersphere, and thus meet Missy.

(It’s also worth bearing in mind that Clara previously

> saved the Doctor by jumping into his time stream, and by convincing the Time Lords to send him a new set of regenerations.

Without her, there may not have *been* a Doctor to come and meet Missy.)

This just about makes sense in terms of Missy’s ultimate plan (although see also [@delinear’s answer below](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72329/440)), which was

> to force the Doctor to accept control of the Cyberman army, and give in to a lust for power, therefore becoming closer to Missy, and possibly joining her to travel time and space. (The Master is basically lonely in New Who.)

She wanted the Doctor to be there when she put her plan into motion, and interfering more directly in his time stream to make that happen would likely have alerted the Doctor to her presence and/or her plan.

Comment: Plus, Missy is *bananas*. And we know how passionate the Doctor is about those.

Comment: Also, without Clara there would be no Missy.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: how so?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Because without her the War Doctor would have used the moment and sealed the Time War, rather than pulling Gallifrey into another dimension at the last second, which is how Missy survived.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: very true!

Answer (score 5):

Missy said she wanted to pair the control freak with the uncontrollable man, and if you think about it, a huge chunk of this series has been about the Doctor and Clara battering their heads together. Maybe Missy just wanted the Doctor continuously occupied with an unsolvable problem (after all, Clara is the impossible girl) so he wouldn't be able to connect the dots on her wider plan.

The idea of it being a trap, so that Clara would force the Doctor into visiting the Nethersphere, sounds tempting, but it relies on far too many variables that were beyond Missy's control (or at least that we didn't see her trying to control - she introduced the two before Clara and Danny were a thing, she didn't appear instrumental in them not breaking up, she had no reasonable way to predict how Clara would react in her grief, etc). Ultimately the Doctor's own curiosity is all the reason she would have needed to draw him in, and they could have easily met outside of the Nethersphere with exactly the same result, so Clara's needing to focus on the subject of her grief was similarly a useful but unnecessary coincidence in getting all parties together.

Comment: +1 from me i strongly agree with the pairing of the control freak and uncontrollable man. Perhaps, the plan of pairing the Doctor and Clara also might have been to condition the Doctor into following orders. (i.e. to take the army and travel with Missy)